# Finding model for categorical Data

Tags: r, regression, categorical-data, biostatistics, categorical-encoding

I'm trying to find out a model that adequately describes effects of gender and length on food choice. For gender; 0=Male and 1=Female, length; 0=Subadult 1=Adult, Choice; F=Fish I=Invertebrates and O=Others.

```
data3 <- data.frame(
  gender = c(0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 1, 1, 
             1,1, 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
             1,1,1,1,1), 
  length = c(0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
             0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
             1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
             1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
  choice = c("I","F", "F","F", "I","F","I","F", "I","I","I", "O","O","I","F","F","I","O","F","O","F","F","I","F","I",
             "F","F","F","F","F","O","O",
             "F","F","F","F", "O","F","F","I","I","I","O","I","I","I","F","I","O","I","I","F","F","F","F","F","F","F","O","F","I",
             "F","F")
)
```

I tried two models;

```
    model = loglm(~ length + gender + choice, Table)
    summary(model)

    addict.mult0= multinom(choice ~ gender + length, data3)
    summary( addict.mult0)
```

But I would like also to have a model that only consider Female Adult for the different type of Food (something like this)

[image]

Could someone help me?

Comment: As an answer says, it's not completely clear what your overall goal is or what hypothesis you're testing. It's possible to start with a full model on all the data and then extract predictions for specific subsets or combinations of variables (and even doing formal hypothesis tests on those predictions). That's usually better than modeling subsets of data. But how to do that here depends on what you are specifically looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It is not entirely clear what is your ultimate goal, can you edit your post to specify your research question? In the meantime, maybe what you need is a contingency table separately for each gender. I get

```r
xtabs( ~ length + choice, data4, subset=gender=="F")                
          choice
length      F  I  O
  subadult  1  8  2
  adult    16  2  2
```

which is clear enough, subadults seems to avoid fish.

Here is the code to replicate this, starting with your code above:

```r
data4 <- within(data3,{gender <- factor(gender,labels=c("M","F"))
                       length <- factor(length,labels=c("subadult","adult"))
                       choice <- as.factor(choice)})
```